# Spring application Jenkins deployment - environments

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jenkins, spring-boot, jenkins-workflow

I am having the following deployment pipeline for a Spring application (Maven).

Build -> DEV -> TST -> PROD

The war file is build in the first step then copied to each environment. The Problem I am facing now is that I need different properties for the different environments. I have created the following property files:

- application-dev.properties
- application-int.properties
- application-prod.properties

What is best practice to automatically assign the correct environments to each deployment step so that the corrosponding property file for each environment is chosen automatically.

For local testing I have used the following. But I dont know how to transfer that to Jenkins.

-Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active="int"

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to follow [12 FActor App](http://12factor.net/config) principles, where all properties are passed into your app via environment variables. That would conform to "cloud native" application.

But if you don't want to do that, you can use it the way you are describing. Property `spring.profiles.active` will be configured on runtime, not in Jenkins build. All config files can be included in WAR file. It's very inflexible, because as some environment properties change, you will need to kick off new build -> new version.

Biggest problem with this approach is that it doesn't scale. In cloud environment, you may want to have a lot of different PROD environments with different configurations. If your WAR artifact locked configuration withing single config file, you have only one PROD configuration.

Some deployment systems work the way that configuration files have placeholders and you replace these placeholders during deployment. So you can have one PROD configuration file, but deployment pipeline will replace placeholders with values for different PROD nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have several options: 
If you insist to use the same build war for all environments you can add a `Global MAVEN_OPTS` : in Jenkins go to main menu `Manage Jenkins->Configure System` and try to set the `Global MAVEN_OPTS`  with :
 `-Dspring.profiles.active=int`

Another option should be to use the Maven Profile to build a specific war with the appropriate properties file in Jenkins. And so in your Jenkins job configuration add the `goals and options` maven command in the build step (for i.e.  `clean install –Pint` where "int" is your Maven profile id for Jenkins